# Use a same package file for all sub-packages in scala

Tags: scala, package

I have a package object with some implicit classes in a package say `x`. Lets call it being in a file `x.scala`. I have two subpackages `x.a` and `x.b`. I need to use the same implicit classes in the two subpackages as well. 
As of now I have made package objects for the two subpackages in: `a.scala` and `b.scala` and replicated the code for the implicit class in the two objects.
There must be a way this can be done in a better manner. Can I somehow use the package object of `x` package and use it in the two subpackages?

Comment: The correct terminology is “package object,” not “package file.”

Answer (score 7):

Declare packages a and b like this:

```
package x
package a
```

and

```
package x
package b
```

This is sorta like saying `package x.a` followed by `import x`.  Then you should have access to all of your implicit stuff in `x`.

Comment: This will also expose all my classes, objects etc of the parent package into the sub-packages. Right?